# What are Tower[A] and IvoryTower in Scalaz?

Tags: scala, scalaz, io-monad

When I looked at `scalaz.effect.IO` source code, I noticed that it has a method `apply` with the following signature:

```
sealed trait IO[A] {
  def apply(rw: Tower[IvoryTower]): Trampoline[(Tower[IvoryTower], A)]
}
```

`Tower[A]` and `IvoryTower` are defined as:

```
case class Tower[A]()
sealed trait IvoryTower
```

There is one instance of `Tower`:

```
object IvoryTower extends IvoryTowers

trait IvoryTowers {
  val ivoryTower = Tower[IvoryTower]()
}
```

What is the purpose of these classes? Why does `IO.apply` accepts an argument of type `Tower[IvoryTower]`?

Comment: I too wish Scalaz were documented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an in-joke: `IvoryTower` is a port of a Haskell type called `RealWorld`. (I do wish it had a clearer name - this one manages to be both impenetrable to newcomers and not actually funny). See e.g. https://wiki.haskell.org/IO_inside .

Comment: Why is it called IvoryTower? Why not FunnyBanana or IntrepidTiger?

Comment: Because an ivory tower is supposed to be the opposite of the real world. https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aivory%20tower